# When is a bold font not bold? (Table of Contents)

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am using an external program which can generate an index from a pdf document based on words which display in bold. When I create my document in LaTeX, the article headings and ToC contain words in bold. Yet they are not recognized by the external program. Is there something in the LaTeX or pdf internals to explain why words which properly display in bold are not recognized as bold except by the eye?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{Important Article}
\author{Unaffiliated Author}
\date{}
\usepackage{mathpazo} %I don't know if this affects the answer
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Article $[$1$]$ Bacon}

Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner ball tip chuck rump. Pig meatball jowl,      bresaola pastrami chicken ball tip venison beef ribs andouille pork loin leberkas. Tongue alcatra brisket, sausage andouille pork belly chuck doner ball tip meatball hamburger salami. Turducken tongue pork belly, hamburger boudin rump meatball chicken fatback cupim capicola chuck spare ribs. Tail kevin prosciutto ham chicken.


\section{Article $[$2$]$ Pork}

Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner ball tip chuck rump. Pig meatball jowl, bresaola pastrami chicken ball tip venison beef ribs andouille pork loin leberkas. Tongue alcatra brisket, sausage andouille pork belly chuck doner ball tip meatball hamburger salami. Turducken tongue pork belly, hamburger boudin rump meatball chicken fatback cupim capicola chuck spare ribs. Tail kevin prosciutto ham chicken.

\section{Article $[$3$]$ Ribs}

Bacon ipsum dolor amet doner ball tip chuck rump. Pig meatball jowl,    bresaola pastrami chicken ball tip venison beef ribs andouille pork loin leberkas. Tongue alcatra brisket, sausage andouille pork belly chuck doner ball tip meatball hamburger salami. Turducken tongue pork belly, hamburger boudin rump meatball chicken fatback cupim capicola chuck spare ribs. Tail kevin prosciutto ham chicken.

\end{document}
```

Update: The LaTeX default is to embed fonts. I don't know if unembedding them would fix the problem.

Trying \pdfcompresslevel=0 had no effect.

Comment: I have tested this with Adobe Reader and Okular (both on Linux) and **bold** is **bold** -- which external program do you mean?

Comment: It's a commercial program. They are trying hard to fix the problem but so far have not been successful.

Comment: Well, there's not much we can do here to fix an issue with pdf etc rendering in an 'external' program

Comment: the document uses three fonts `AGQKFS+URWPalladioL-Roma` , `KUTYPQ+URWPalladioL-Bold`,  `CHOTJT+CMR10` all denoting subsetted fonts, you could try generating a pdf without compression `\pdfcompresslevel=0` and without font subsetting (modify the palladio map file)  and then see if it picks up URWPalladioL-Bold as bold

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank you. How do I do that? Add \pdfcompresslevel=0 before \begin{document}?

Comment: that would work, yes

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Fair enough, but there seems to be a difference between pdf files created with LaTeX and those created with other programs, e.g., Word, Libre Office, Mellel, etc.

Comment: probably they are using truetype or opentype fonts rather than type1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle RE: "modifying the palladio map file"/without font subsetting: how can I accomplish either of these? Is there a setting in LaTeX to insure that fonts won't be subsetted?

Comment: sigh not done that by hand since last century I was hoping someone else would pass by and answer that, I'll look later if no one else has answered:-)

Comment: I generated the file using XeLatex and an otf file as well--but I didn't get a bold font in either the article headers or the ToC. The font I used was the Bembo family, but there are threads about odd font behavior under OS X El Capitan.